# Remove parenthesis around year from citation with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I want to remove the parenthesis around the year from a citation using biblatex. Hopefully the code and screenshot of the outputted PDF explains what I'm currently getting and what I need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=50]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IngerEtAl2006using,
  title={Using daily ration models and stable isotope analysis to predict biomass depletion by herbivores},
  author={Inger, Richard and Ruxton, Graeme D and Newton, Jason and Colhoun, Kendrew and Mackie, Kerry and Robinson, James A and Bearhop, Stuart},
  journal={Journal of Applied Ecology},
  volume={43},
  number={5},
  pages={1022--1030},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library},
  tag={}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    This line shows how the citations appears in the PDF (e.g. \textcite{IngerEtAl2006using})\\\\

    I want the citation to appear like this: (e.g. Inger et al. 2006).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\parencite[e.g.][]{IngerEtAl2006using}`. And don't use ` \\\\ ` if you don't want tons of "underfull hbox" messages. Enlarge `\parskip` if you want more space between paragraphs.

Comment: That's done it. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\parencite[e.g.][]{IngerEtAl2006using}` instead of `\textcite` in parentheses.

And don't use `\\\\` if you don't want tons of "underfull hbox" messages. Enlarge \parskip if you want more space between paragraphs.